# What is the differences with having a `<link rel="stylesheet" href=..video.scss` in the index.html vs using `import '../video.scss`

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm a beginner at React.js and I notice that for stylesheets some do like this in a React Component:

`import '../../styles/video.scss`

and some do like this in the index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
```

When to use what and what is preferred to use with ReactJs?

Answer (score 2):

```
import '../../styles/video.scss'
```

This is definitely the way to go.

The major difference is that things imported this way will be pulled through the webpack pipeline, such as loaders. The loader responsible for transpiling SASS looks for ES6 imports, and it cannot transpile `link`s in the index. In simple words, you cannot import sass & friends as a `link`.

Another thing is that you keep tossing things into the index, it'll grow really quickly and get messy.

Besides, your case mentions only global css imports, and this is the only thing you can do via a `link` inside the index. Things like modular css are only available as module imports.